# Interpretation of tree in R

Tags: r, regression, interpretation

[image: A picture of the tree I'm supposed to interpret]

Hi, I'm supposed to interpret this tree. I have two questions:

1. In R, which branch is "yes" and which is "no" in a split? (left or right branch?)
2. I want to find out if age is a more important predictor than sex. I would say that it is, since age makes a split on a higher level than sex, but age splits 3 times, how do I interpret that?

Comment: Isn't the answer to (1) obvious by inspection?  For instance, would it be make any sense to compare `age` to 46.5 once you have determined `age` is at least 81.5?

Comment: Maybe it is? As  Patrick Bormann said, it makes sense that the left branch is yes.

Answer (score 0):

The left branch is a yes in R, see also here:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decision-trees-R

There is an R output of your model that gives you the importance of your features.
In case you want to calculate them manually:
Here is a like that shows you with an example, how you can calculate the feature importance (known from sklearn) for all your features, thus you would finally know which feature is better separator:

https://sefiks.com/2020/04/06/feature-importance-in-decision-trees/

The formula is (excerpt):

> Feature importance (FI) = Feature metric * number of instances – its
> left child node metric * number of instances for the left child – its
> right child node metric * number of instances for the right child

This example is for entropy. To summarise, a higher split at the beginning does not necessarily guarantee to be that the feature is of higher importance. It also depends on the number of cases/instances a separator can catch for dividng. As you will see in the example, so yes it may be that age is a good separator and of higher importance.